# Interpretation of area under the precision-recall curve

Tags: machine-learning, roc, auc, precision-recall

The area under the receiver-operator characteristic curve has a interpretation of how well the predictions of two categories are separated.

[This](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/306085/247274) post gives the area under the precision-recall curve as the average precision across all thresholds. This is unsatisfying. Are there other interpretations?

Comment: I believe you are basically making the same question as the post you linked

Comment: @Firebug That one seemed to be specific to average precision, while I am looking for other interpretations (which might not exist), though if this gets closed as a duplicate, I won’t go on Meta to request it be reopened.

Comment: I think there are not really any other ones. I would also see this in reverse too, as there is no literature associating AUC-RP with any known statistical tests. If there were such tests, it would indicate some additional interpretation. (Of course, the absence of evidence is not the evidence for absence, but I am pretty sure many people have tried to create "that evidence" already.) What I have seen is the Precision-Recall-*Gain* curve being associated with the expected $F_1$ score but that's "reaching" as it is not really the AUPR curve.